# using include(''<filename>) vs using class in php

Tags: php

In my project i have to create a lot of php function for various purpose. My question is which will be better approach for my project

1. separate the functions in .php file and include them as i necessary, or
2. bind the functions inside classes and use those class like object oriented approach

Comment: it highly depends on what kind of functions they are.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, procedural programming is fine. Using OOPS in php for the sake of using it is useless.

However IMHO, you use OOP to keep your code DRY and clean. 
If most of your functions relate to the same stuff(like a shopping cart for eg) it is better to group them.

If your are going to use **inheritance** or **polymorphism** or set properties and have few stuff `private` then its best to use OOP approach there.

it highly depends on what kind of functions they do.

The issue here may be of code organization rather than deciding to pick procedural or object-oriented programming approach. Organizing functions into separate source files may be what's needed here than to abandon the procedural approach to writing the program

Answer (score 0):

Separate class file, so you can reuse your code more easily.

Comment: I also like to use classes as i do in c# or java codding but i have a doubt that php is not a powerful OOPS oriented language like c# and  java so if we use class in case of just raw file will it behave as enhancement of my project?

Answer (score 0):

Second approach will make code robust and easy to understand for other developer for future prespective and best approach for me as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping the functions is a good thing if those are under the same category.Otherwise group the functions using classes based on categories.